# Passing all object files in the project directory tree to a rule in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile that looks like this

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-pedantic -ansi -Wall -O2
TARGET=assembler
SUBDIRS = utils preprocessor parser symbols

.PHONY: clean all subdirs $(SUBDIRS)

subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@

all: subdirs

clean: 
    for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
        $(MAKE) -C $$dir clean; \
    done
```

And I want to add

```
$(TARGET): subdirs $(TARGET).c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(TARGET).c -o $@
```

But then I get linking error because the objects files from the subdirs aren't found. Is there a way to pass all object files under the project root directory?

Comment: Do you want all object files under the project root directory, (which I presume is the working directory, the one containing `utils`, `preprocessor`, and so on), or just the object files in the named subdirectories? Also, since this use of Make is recursive (i.e. it calls itself on each of the subdirectories), it sacrifices some handy features of Make, such as keeping track of object files. Would you be interested in a non-recursive Make setup?

Comment: Spoiler alert: Glob/wildcard is bad. List the object files manually. Faster to do, faster to run, and everybody gets it. No caveats.

Comment: @Beta yes all objects under the subdirectories. Is there a better way to do this non-recursive? Wouldn't make the makefile much more complex?

Comment: @Andreas you mean doing something like `OBJECTS=\`find . -name "*.o"\`` and then `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(TARGET).c $(OBJECTS)-o $@`?

Comment: @CforLinux, no, I meant manually entering `$(TARGET): utils/a.o utils/b.o parser/parser.o ...` etc. Objects in different subfolders preferably listed under separate variables, but that's just style. Use `find . -name "*.c"` to find the objects, then transcript.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to pass all object files under the project root directory?

Usage of the word "pass" suggests that you have altogether the wrong mental model of makefiles and `make` operation.  Makefiles are *specifications*, not scripts, and the rules within are not functions and do not operate like functions.  Among other things, the targets and prerequisites of explicit rules are determined when the makefile is parsed, not dynamically at the time of (consideration of) rule execution.

It follows that what you propose to do is altogether unworkable, because you cannot rely on any of the object files -- they being built files -- to exist when `make` starts.  You have a chicken and egg problem.

I fully agree with @Andreas that using globbing and similar dynamic target or prerequisite detection in a makefile is bad.<sup>*</sup>  Targets and prerequisites that are named at all should be named explicitly (not to preclude assigning them to a variable or using substitution references or similar).  But if you nevertheless do use globbing or another form of dynamic detection to locate files, then you should be locating files distributed with the project, not built ones.

If you want to maintain the modularity of your recursive `make` build system (which is [not by any means a clear win](https://grosskurth.ca/bib/1997/miller.pdf)), then one reasonable alternative would be for the `make` in each subdirectory to build a static archive named after the directory name.  The top-level makefile then does not need to know any of the details of the subdirectory `make`s; it just includes the static library resulting from each one in the link.

---

<sup>*</sup>There are multiple reasons for this, but they are tangential to the question at hand.